# Using MockServerHttpResponse to test WebFilter

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, spring-webflux

I have a org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter that I am testing.  I am mocking the ServerWebExchange to return a MockServerHttpResponse.  When the web filter wants to return an error response it uses

```
    private static Mono<Void> setErrorResponse(ServerWebExchange exchange, String message) {
    ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse()
    response.statusCode = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST
    response.getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    DataBuffer buffer = response.bufferFactory().wrap(message.getBytes("UTF-8"))
    return response.writeWith(Flux.just(buffer))
}
```

Then I try to get the the response body by calling

```
response.getBodyAsString().block()
```

But I always get

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No content was written nor was setComplete() called on this response.
```

How do you use the mock to get the response body that does not seem to get set when using writeWith()?

Answer (score 0):

block() has to be called on the Mono result as well.

```
Mono<Void> mono = setErrorResponse(exchange, "ERROR");
mono.block();
Assertions.assertEquals("ERROR",exchange.getResponse().getBodyAsString().block());
```